# Python cannot execute file

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I created a function which convert any user defined value into its corresponding value. At first, this function will initialize an array and did some modification to its input. I can confirm that the error lies with this function, since after I remove this particular piece of code, everything works fine.

```
def get_lower_page(input):
   #initialize the array
   convpage=[0]*1535
   for k in range(16):
     for m in range(2,36):
        if m==2:
            lp=k
            convpage[lp]=lp
        elif m==3:
            up=32*m+2*k-79
            lp=up-1
            convpage[lp]=lp
            convpage[up]=lp
        elif (m==4 or m==5):
            xp=48*m+3*k-80
            up=32*m+2*k-79
            lp=up-1
            convpage[xp]=lp
            convpage[lp]=lp
            convpage[up]=lp
        elif (m>5 and m<33):
            xp=48*m+2*k-80
            up=48*m+3*k-174
            lp=up-1
            convpage[xp]=lp
            convpage[lp]=lp
            convpage[up]=lp
        elif m==33:
            xp=48*m+2*k-80
            up=48*m+3*k-174
            lp=up-1
            convpage[xp]=lp
            convpage[lp]=lp
            convpage[up]=lp
        elif m=34:
            up=48*m+3*k-174
            lp=up-1
            convpage[lp]=lp
            convpage[up]=lp
        else:
            lp=48*m+2*k-175
            convpage[lp]=lp

    return convpage[input]
```

This function will be called inside the program, for example:

```
get_lower_page(21), which returns 20 to the calling function
```

I don't think the detail of how the function works is needed here. Can anybody spot the mistake?

Comment: an error would be helpful....

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and edit accordingly with whatever error you are getting or any other description of the behaviour you expect, the one you get and how they differ.

Comment: You don't need to "suspect" a syntax error; the compiler/interpreter will tell you.

Comment: No error message, since the executable file itself can't be opened

Comment: The indentation of `return convpage[input]` is wrong

Comment: @Chris I don't think so, I have edited this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a syntax error. On this line:

```
elif m=34:
```

Should be:

```
elif m==34:
```

Also, your `return` needs to be indented, and this block:

```
else:
        lp=48*m+2*k-175
        convpage[lp]=lp
```

Return an index out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case when k=15 and m=35

```
lp = 48*m+2*k-175
convpage[lp]=lp
```

lp = 48*35+2*15-175=1535. But you initialized the array as `convpage=[0]*1535`, so `convpage[lp]=lp` will throw an error as the index is outside the range by 1.